# Streaming audio via http

Tags: java, android, audio, streaming, android-mediaplayer

Given an audio `.mp3` file how could one create an audio stream from this file and share it as url `"http://..."`. I have actually tried to implement a Servlet that would serve my file to a MediaPlayer object but it seems that when requesting the servlet, one would rather download the file instead of getting the audio stream (the `onPrepared` condition for the mediaPlayer is forever set to false although the process keeps running). Here is the source code :

```
button_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            try{
                mPlayer.reset();                   
                mPlayer.setDataSource("http://localhost:8080/FileServlet/song/sample.mp3");                    
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();

                mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
                        mp.start();

                    }
                });

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (SecurityException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    });
```

Any idea please how may I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the MediaPlayer object is the one who decides how to use the "file" : either download it and play it afterwards OR play it as it downloads.

Method 1 is "safe" because server might go down, or some sites dont allow downloads that take more than 15 minutes and tries to disconnect them.Method 2 is bad on slow internet providers (you woudnt want to hear 1 second of music every 5 seconds as it streams)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the source code for more readability.

Comment: :) Try to open with other apps, I remember Opera playing instead of downloading mp3s.